# Using native Android system libraries outside NDK's stable API

Tags: c++, linker, android-ndk, native, android-library

I was wondering if it's possible to use in native code the libraries of the Android system that are not directly exposed as an API from NDK.
In particular how to include them in my native app code so that they can be linked with it.
I know that it is discouraged, but the compatibility of my project across different Android releases is not a concern.

What I'm trying to achieve is to skip some of the services that Android provides and try to sit closer to the kernel.
Thanks.

Comment: you could just pull so from your phone and link against it but what exactly you are trying to achieve? If you want to sit close to kernel just write your own wrappers dealing with interactions you want. What kind of so files you need to have access?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you understand that it is not recommended to have any dependencies on the system libraries beyond the [stable API](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/STABLE-APIS.html). But the open nature of Android allows (both technically and in terms of licensing) to introduce such dependencies. Essentially it means sailing in the non-chartered waters, and being prepared to API changes not only in the next version of the platform, but also in a vendor-provided (i.e. non-AOSP) setups of the same platform level.

The safest way to ensure forward (and vendor) compatibility is to use [dynamic linking](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-ndk/sOGz0nyLbg4/discussion) for the undocumented system features, and perform careful error checking on the way.

But in many cases, the system undocumented APIs are actually quite stable, and the nice people in the Android team of Google do not make breaking changes too often. Therefore, if you link against the 4.0 version of **skia** your code will most likely simply work on 4.1.2 and on.

Technically, you will need the headers to compile and the **.so** files to link against. The latter you can simply `adb pull /system/lib/lib`*whatever*`.so` from your own device, or from an emulator image. The headers you can download from https://android.googlesource.com/ git repository. Make sure your headers match the libraries version.

Comment: Doesn't pulling the .so files like that give you platform specific .so files?

Comment: @Mark, yes, these are platform specific libraries. The last thing you want to do is to copy them to a different device or version. But we need them only to link, listing them in `LOCAL_LDLIBS`, not `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES `